# Could someone explain why my Adjacent Selector isn't working as expected in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#collapsible").click(function () {
        $("h3 + *").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="collapsible">Technical Specs:</h3> <!-- Needs to be clickable -->
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>

<h3 id="collapsible">Ordering Information</h3>
<p>To order please call us at 0-000-000-0000</p>
```

It was my understanding based on a number of CSS tutorials that **`x + y`** would select any **`y`** that comes immediately after **`x`**. So I thought **`h3 + *`** would select Any (wildcard) element that comes directly after my h3. But it's not working as I expected, **why is that**?

Comment: You have 2 elements with the same ID. If you're clicking `Ordering Information`, then no, it won't work.

Comment: Duplicate `id`s is invalid markup.  The behavior is entirely undefined until the markup is fixed.

Comment: @Squint okay so the CSS selector is working correctly, its just finding both Collapsibles? If you want to leave that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: No, it's only finding the first one. jQuery will stop after the first match because it uses `getElementById` when your selector is only for an ID, and `getElementById` never finds more than one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 elements with the same ID. If you're clicking *Ordering Information*, then no, it won't work because it's only finding the first one.

The reason jQuery will only return a single match when the selector is only an ID selector is because it optimizes to use `getElementById` in that case, and `getElementById` never finds more than one element.

If you wanted both `h3` elements to be clickable, then make their ID a CLASS instead, and use `$(".collapsible")` to select both. Elements can share a class, and the class selector will return all elements that have that class.

However, in your event handler, you're selecting all `h3 + *` elements, which probably isn't what you want either. If you only want to select the next one, then click use `this`, which represents the element clicked, and navigate over to the next element.

If you wanted to use a selector in that case, you could do this:

```
$("+ h3", this)
```

or just use one of jQuery's DOM selection methods.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I had in jotted down that I think I need to use "this," but I didn't understand why that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code:

#### HTML:

```
<h3 class="collapsible">Technical Specs:</h3> <!-- Needs to be clickable -->
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="collapsible">Ordering Information</h3>       
    <p>To order please call us at 0-000-000-0000</p>
```

#### Jquery:

```
$(".collapsible").click(function(){
    $(this).next("ul").toggle();
    $(this).next("p").toggle();
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ejgk6r42/1/